# Splitting text lines, whilst appending prefix

Tags: regex, awk, sed, text-processing

**EDITED**

I have about 50x9Gb `.mer` files that look like this:

```
"xxxxx";"123\t123\t123\v234\t234\v234\t224\t234\v"
"yyyyy";"123\t234\t224\v234\t234\v234\t224\t234\v"
"zzzzz";"123\t456\t565\v234\t774"
```

A `uuid` followed by `";"` **and then possibly extra tabbed entries**, followed by a vertical tab delimited list of **further multiple tabbed** entries, all enclosed in quotes. I've shown them as 3-digit numbers here, but in reality they're variable length strings, which can include doubled quotes `""`.

I need to turn them into this:

```
xxxxx\t123\t123\t123
xxxxx\t234\t234
xxxxx\t234\t224\t234
yyyyy\t123\t234\t224
yyyyy\t234\t234
yyyyy\t234\t224\t234
zzzzz\t123\t456\t565
zzzzz\t234\t774
```

That is, split the lines on the vertical tabs, prefixing each line with the first field of the line that it came from.

Currently, I'm using a noddy regex, which does at least work, but requires multiple runs and manual checking.

How would I do this using `awk` or `sed` ? I've tried adapting the the current answers below, but I'm having trouble finding out what the ;P and ;D suffixes mean.

(Note: I'm using GitBash on Windows, so I guess that's gnu `sed` and `awk` ?)

Comment: try `awk -F'\t|\v' -v OFS='\t' '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1, $i}' file`

Comment: Thanks Kent, works like a charm!

Comment: ask a new question instead of making the existing answers obsolete

Comment: Sundeep - the existing answers didn't work originally, sadly

Comment: wrt `I've shown them as 3-digit numbers here, but in reality they're variable length strings, which can include doubled quotes ""` - why would you do that? When posting sample input it's important to make it truly representative of your real input. Making it look like everything's a 3-digit number is just asking for a solution that'll only work on 3-digit numbers.

Comment: Are your "variable length strings" guaranteed not to include semi-colons? How about carriage return characters? What is the newline indicator in your file - the UNIX newline `\n` alone or Windows `\r\n`? Can that be inside your fields?

Comment: Well, the lines were about 2k long.... so perhaps that's a good enough reason ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F';' -v OFS='\t'              #set Field separator is ';',
    '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)           #then we have 2 fields, remove leading and trailing doubled qoutes
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$i)
      c=split($2,a,"\v")           #split by vertical tab, save result in array 'a'
      for(i=1;i<=c;i++)            #for each element in a, if it is not empty, print field1 (the uuid)
        if(a[i])print $1,a[i]}' file #and the element, separated by Tab
```

explanation is inline.

It outputs:

```
xxxxx   123     123     123
xxxxx   234     234
xxxxx   234     224     234
yyyyy   123     234     224
yyyyy   234     234
yyyyy   234     224     234
zzzzz   123     456     565
zzzzz   234     774
```

Comment: If I put this on a single line, do I need ';' or something?

Comment: `awk -F';' -v OFS='\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$i);c=split($2,a,"\v");for(i=1;i<=c;i++)if(a[i])print $1,a[i]}' file` @Dycey

Comment: I needed a little Java programming kata and found this question. I am not writing an answer yet because Java is off-topic, but if you are interested, I created a dummy data generator according to your updated specification and created a 9 GB test file. Then I parsed it with this very awk script: 533 s, which I found quite impressive for an interpreted language. Congrats, Kent! But Dycey, just in case performance is a major issue and you are interested, my Java prog runs just 212 s, i.e 2.5x faster (not optimised in any way yet), both progs writing to /dev/null. If you ask me to I can post it.

Comment: @kriegaex Kents current solution is performing multiple time-consuming steps that aren't necessary given the OPs currently posted input so it's no surprise that it's slower than an equivalent java script.. If/when the OP answers the questions I asked in comments under his question then we can start looking at helping him create the best solution for his real input data.

Comment: I think the awk script does not do a lot which would be unnecessary, but it also not replace `""` inside the horizontal + vertical tab delimited value list, which my solution does, so my solution does even a little bit more. But to be fair, Kent wrote his answer before the OP just changed the question. I would not over-optimise anyway, I like readable code, no matter if it is awk, sed or Java code. (Okay, for sed it is harder to achieve, but anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^((\S*\t)\S*)\v/\1\n\2/;P;D' file
```

Replace each `\v` by a newline, the first field and a tab. Print and Delete the first line and repeat.

EDIT: As per the new question;

```
sed -r '/\n/!s/"(")?/\1/g;/\n/!s/;/\t/;s/^((\S*\t)[^\v]*)\v/\1\n\2/;/\t$/!P;D' file
```

Remove any single double quotes (replace double double quotes by single double quotes) and replace the semi colon by a tab character. Then replace any `\v`'s by a newline and the first field and a tab and repeat.

Comment: Your updated sed script completely removes `""` instead of replacing them by `"`. This is not what the updated question describes.

Comment: @kriegaex thanks, I did not take on board that aspect, see edit

Comment: Still does not work. Have you even tested it? It keeps removing all double quotes. You can use my Java test data generator and try it on a file produced by it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk command for this output:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} n = split($2, a, "\x0b") {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print $1, a[i]}' file

195a664e-e0d0-4488-99d6-5504f9178115    1234
195a664e-e0d0-4488-99d6-5504f9178115    1412
195a664e-e0d0-4488-99d6-5504f9178115    1231
195a664e-e0d0-4488-99d6-5504f9178115    4324
195a664e-e0d0-4488-99d6-5504f9178115    1421
195a664e-e0d0-4488-99d6-5504f9178115    3214
a1d61289-7864-40e6-83a7-8bdb708c459e    1412
a1d61289-7864-40e6-83a7-8bdb708c459e    6645
a1d61289-7864-40e6-83a7-8bdb708c459e    5334
a1d61289-7864-40e6-83a7-8bdb708c459e    3453
a1d61289-7864-40e6-83a7-8bdb708c459e    5453
```

**How it works:**

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}       # sets input and output field separator as tab
n = split($2, a, "\x0b") # splits second field using Hex 0B (ASCII 11) i.e. vertical tab
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) ... # prints pair of field 1 with each item from split array a
```

Answer (score 0):

gnu sed

```
 sed  's/"\|..$//g;s/;/\t/;:r;s/^\([^\t]*\)\t\(.*\)\\v/\1\t\2\n\1\t/;t r;s/\\t/\t/g;'  YourFile
```

recursive replace of \v by first "field" + tab + cleaning extra char on the way

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `awk`

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS="[\v;]"}
   {
       gsub("[\"]",""); 
       for(i=2; i<=NF; ++i) 
           if($i) printf "%s\t%s\n", $1, $i;
   }' file.mer
```

Another solution using `sed`

```
sed -r 's/\v\n/\v/g; s/"//g;
    :a; s/([^;]*);([^\v]*)\v/\1;\2\n\1;/g; ta; 
    s/;/\t/g;' file.mer | sed -r '/^[^\t]+\t$/d'
```

you get,

```
xxxxx   123 123 123
xxxxx   234 234
xxxxx   234 224 234
yyyyy   123 234 224
yyyyy   234 234
yyyyy   234 224 234
zzzzz   123 456 565
zzzzz   234 774
```

Comment: Both your awk and sed scripts completely remove `""` instead of replacing them by `"`. This is not what the updated question describes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I waited on purpose until Kent's answer was accepted and awarded the bounty because the question was about awk/sed. Thus, my answer might be somewhat off-topic, but anyway here is my Java solution which I did just for fun as a kata.

**MER input file generator:**

I thought it would be nice to generate some sample input files with randomised values. Each line consists of

- a UUID,
- 0-9 groups, separated by vertical tabs,
- within each group, 1-4 strings, separated by horizontal tabs,
- each string consisting of 1-20 characters, among them double quotes escaped by other double quotes, i.e. `""`.

I thought this is diverse enough to get some good test data.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;

public class RandomFileGenerator {
  private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;
  private final static Random RANDOM = new Random();
  private final static char VERTICAL_TAB = '\u000b';
  private final static char[] LEGAL_CHARS =
    "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöüÄÖÜß. -\""
      .toCharArray();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//    final long maxOutputSize = 9L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
//    final String outputFile = "src/main/resources/sample-9gb.mer";
    final long maxOutputSize = 1L * 1024 * 1024;
    final String outputFile = "src/main/resources/sample-1mb.mer";
    long totalOutputSize = 0;
    long lineCount = 0;
    String line;
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile), BUFFER_SIZE))) {
      while (totalOutputSize < maxOutputSize) {
        line = generateLine();
        writer.println(generateLine());
        totalOutputSize += line.length() + 1;
        lineCount++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(lineCount);
    System.out.println(totalOutputSize);
    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0);
  }

  private static String generateLine() {
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    buffer
      .append('"')
      .append(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
      .append("\";\"");
    int numItems = RANDOM.nextInt(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
      int numSubItems = 1 + RANDOM.nextInt(4);
      for (int j = 0; j < numSubItems; j++) {
        buffer.append(
          RandomStringUtils.random(1 + RANDOM.nextInt(20), 0, LEGAL_CHARS.length, false, false, LEGAL_CHARS)
            .replaceAll("\"", "\"\"")
        );
        if (j + 1 < numSubItems)
          buffer.append('\t');
      }
      if (i + 1 < numItems) {
        buffer.append(VERTICAL_TAB);
      }
    }
    buffer.append('"');
    return buffer.toString();
  }

}
```

You can see that it is easy to create test files of the desired file size, e.g.

- 1 MB: `maxOutputSize = 1L * 1024 * 1024`
- 9 GB: `maxOutputSize = 9L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024`

I mostly used the smaller one to check the algorithms during development and the really big one for performance tuning.

**File splitter in 4 different variants:**

The variants shown here use different approaches, but in common they have that they read from a `BufferedReader` with Java streams via `reader.lines()`. Switching from streams to a simple `for` loop made it slower, BTW. All solutions write the results into a `PrintWriter`.

1. `reader.lines().forEach()` and then regex matching + splitting. This solution has the best trade-off between readability, brevity and performance.
2. `reader.lines().flatMap()`, i.e. using sub-streams for the vertical-tab-separated groups after the UUID, also using regex matching + splitting. This solution is also quite short and elegant, but a little harder to read than #1 and also about 15% slower.
3. Because regex matching calls like `replace()` and `split()` can be pretty expensive, I developed a solution that rather iterates over the string and uses `indexOf()` and `substring()` instead of regexes. This was substantially faster than #1 and #2, but the code is harder to read in a way I started to dislike. This should only be done if performance is really important, i.e if the file splitter is used regularly. For a one-time solution or if it runs just once a month, I think it is not really worth it from a maintainability standpoint.
4. A further optimised version of #3 which avoids some more overhead and is again a little bit faster, but not substantially. Now the code really needs source code comments so as to convey to the reader what the algorithm does. From a clean code perspective this is a nightmare. (Don't do this at home, kids!)

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FileSplitter {
  private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;
  private static final Pattern LINE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^\"([^\"]+)\";\"(.*)\"$");
  private final static char VERTICAL_TAB = '\u000b';

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String inputFile = "src/main/resources/sample-9gb.mer";
    String outputFile = inputFile.replaceFirst("mer$", "txt");
    try (
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile), BUFFER_SIZE);
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile), BUFFER_SIZE))
    ) {
//      forEachVariant(reader, writer);
//      flatMapVariant(reader, writer);
      noRegexSimpleVariant(reader, writer);
//      noRegexOptimisedVariant(reader, writer);
    }
    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0);
  }

  private static void forEachVariant(BufferedReader reader, PrintWriter writer) {
    Matcher matcher = LINE_PATTERN.matcher("dummy");
    reader.lines()
      .forEach(line -> {
        matcher.reset(line).matches();
        for (String record : matcher.group(2).replace("\"\"", "\"").split("\\v"))
          writer.println(matcher.group(1) + "\t" + record);
      });
  }

  private static void flatMapVariant(BufferedReader reader, PrintWriter writer) {
    Matcher matcher = LINE_PATTERN.matcher("dummy");
    reader.lines()
      .flatMap(line -> {
        matcher.reset(line).matches();
        return Arrays
          .stream(matcher.group(2).replace("\"\"", "\"").split("\\v"))
          .map(record -> matcher.group(1) + "\t" + record);
      })
      .forEach(writer::println);
  }

  private static void noRegexSimpleVariant(BufferedReader reader, PrintWriter writer) {
    reader.lines()
      .forEach(line -> {
        final int lineLength = line.length();

        // UUID + '\t'
        int indexLeft = 1;
        int indexRight = line.indexOf('"', indexLeft);
        final String uuid = line.substring(indexLeft, indexRight) + "\t";

        indexLeft = indexRight + 3;
        String record;
        int quoteIndex;
        while (indexLeft < lineLength) {
          writer.print(uuid);
          indexRight = line.indexOf(VERTICAL_TAB, indexLeft);
          if (indexRight == -1)
            indexRight = lineLength - 1;

          while (indexLeft < indexRight) {
            quoteIndex = line.indexOf('"', indexLeft);
            if (quoteIndex == -1 || quoteIndex >= indexRight)
              quoteIndex = indexRight;
            else
              quoteIndex++;
            record = line.substring(indexLeft, quoteIndex);
            writer.print(record);
            indexLeft = quoteIndex + 1;
          }
          writer.println();
          indexLeft = indexRight + 1;
        }
      });
  }

  private static void noRegexOptimisedVariant(BufferedReader reader, PrintWriter writer) throws IOException {
    reader.lines()
      .forEach(line -> {
        // UUID + '\t'
        int indexLeft = 1;
        int indexRight = line.indexOf('"', indexLeft);
        final String uuid = line.substring(indexLeft, indexRight) + "\t";

        // Skip '";"' after UUID
        indexLeft = indexRight + 3;

        final int lineLength = line.length();
        String recordChunk;
        int quoteIndex;

        // If search for '"' has once reached end of line, search no more
        boolean doQuoteSearch = true;

        // Iterate over records per UUID, separated by vertical tab
        while (indexLeft < lineLength) {
          writer.print(uuid);
          indexRight = line.indexOf(VERTICAL_TAB, indexLeft);
          if (indexRight == -1)
            indexRight = lineLength - 1;

          // Search for '""' within record incrementally, + replace each of them by '"'.
          // BTW, if '"' is found, it actually always will be an escaped '""'.
          while (indexLeft < indexRight) {
            if (doQuoteSearch) {
              // Only search for quotes if we never reached the end of line before
              quoteIndex = line.indexOf('"', indexLeft);
              assert quoteIndex != -1;
              if (quoteIndex >= lineLength - 1)
                doQuoteSearch = false;
              if (quoteIndex >= indexRight)
                quoteIndex = indexRight;
              else
                quoteIndex++;
            }
            else {
              // No more '"' within record
              quoteIndex = indexRight;
            }

            // Write record chunk, skipping 2nd '"'
            recordChunk = line.substring(indexLeft, quoteIndex);
            writer.print(recordChunk);
            indexLeft = quoteIndex + 1;
          }

          // Do not forget newline before reading next line/UUID
          writer.println();
          indexLeft = indexRight + 1;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

**Updated awk script:**

Besides: Each Java solution writes out one UUID without any content in case there was none in the input file. This would be easy to avoid, but I did it on purpose. This is the only difference to this slightly updated awk script (based on Dave's, but also replaces `""` by `"`) which I used as a benchmark:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$i)
    gsub(/""/,"\"",$i)
  }
  c=split($2,a,"\\v")
  for(i=1;i<=c;i++)
    print $1,a[i]
}
```

**Performance results:**

I measured both parsing and writing performance.

- Parsing means reading a 9 GB file from disk and splitting it, but writing the output to /dev/null or not at all.
- Writing means reading the same 9 GB file and writing it back onto the same disk partition (hybrid HD + SSD type), i.e. this could be further optimised by writing onto another physical disk. The output file has a size of 18 GB.

  1. Reading file, splitting into lines but not parsing the lines: 66 s
  2. Awk

     - parsing only: 533 s
     - parsing + writing: 683 s
  3. `reader.lines().forEach()` and then regex matching + splitting

     - parsing only: 212 s
     - parsing + writing: 425 s
  4. `reader.lines().flatMap()`, i.e. using sub-streams

     - parsing only: 245 s
     - parsing + writing: not measured
  5. Without using regex, but using `String.replace("\"\"", "\"")` (not shown in code here)

     - parsing only: 154 s
     - parsing + writing: 369 s
  6. No regex, no `replace()`, simple version

     - parsing only: 86 s
     - parsing + writing: 342 s
  7. No regex, no `replace()`, optimised version

     - parsing only: 84 s
     - parsing + writing: 342 s

Sorry for the lengthy treatise, but I wanted to share my findings for others reading the question and the other answers, speculating whether Java (or C?) might be faster than awk - yes, it is by a substantial bit, but not by an order of magnitude because disk performance is also a factor. And I think it is a warning to those who tend to over-optimise for optimisation's sake. It is not worth it if you go to far, just try to hit the sweet spot between effort, readability and performance. Amen.

Comment: Thanks kriegaex! But sadly, Java is a no-go in client's shop. :-(

Comment: Not even when it is superior to a sed/awk script under these circumstances? Politics with killer arguments. Nice client. ;-) Thanks for the feedback.